# Sorting array which contain mixed string php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a problem with sorting array which contain mixed string.

String contains both number and characters. I want to Sort array with integer number which string contain.

Also sorting should be in alphabetical order.

Please take a look on Result array and My Required array.

My Current Array

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => B2(14) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => G3(14) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => A3(14) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => B13(16) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => A13(16) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [title] => A13(15) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [title] => D13(15) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [title] => A13(13) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

)
```

Function which i am using to sort array is as below

```html
uasort($array,'my_post_sort');

function my_post_sort($a,$b) {

   $akey = $a['title'];

   if (preg_match_all('/\d+/',$akey,$matches)) {

      $akey = sprintf('%010d ',$matches[0][1]);
   }
   $bkey = $b['title'];
   if (preg_match_all('/\d+/',$bkey,$matches)) {
      $bkey = sprintf('%010d ',$matches[0][1]);
   }

   if ($akey == $bkey) {

      return 0;
   }

   return ($bkey > $akey) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Result which i am getting using above code is as below

```html
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => B13(16) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => A13(16) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [title] => A13(15) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [title] => D13(15) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => B2(14) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => G3(14) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => A3(14) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [title] => A13(13) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

)
```

What is my requirement is as below

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => A3(14) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => B2(14) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => G3(14) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => A13(16) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => B13(16) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [title] => A13(15) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [title] => D13(15) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [title] => A13(13) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

)
```

[Please see screenshot](http://prntscr.com/chw5mz)

Comment: Are you sorting against just the characters prior to the left parenthesis? If so, when the integers are the same, what is your second sort condition?

Comment: Your required sorting is sorted only locally - you can't have general loop solving this imo. I'd bet on 3 loops: (1) for string split/decomposition and grouping (with order of appearence), (2) for sorting sub groups created in (1) and another one (3) for recomposition (possibly within (2)).

Answer (score 0):

From my best interpretations of what you're asking for - sort by the number immediately following the letter (not the one in the parens), then the letter, your 'desired results' would have the first two entries the wrong way round.

But try this out and see if it works for your requirements (I also sort by the number in the parens as a last resort):

```
$a = [
    ['title' => 'B2(14) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'],
    ['title' => 'G3(14) consectetur adipiscing elit'],
    ['title' => 'A3(14) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'],
    ['title' => 'B13(16) consectetur adipiscing elit'],
    ['title' => 'A13(16) consectetur adipiscing elit'],
    ['title' => 'A13(15) consectetur adipiscing elit'],
    ['title' => 'D13(15) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'],
    ['title' => 'A13(13) consectetur adipiscing elit'],
];

uasort($a, function($a, $b) {
    $partsA = $partsB = [];
    preg_match('!^([A-Z]+)(\d+)\((\d+)\) !i', $a['title'], $partsA);
    preg_match('!^([A-Z]+)(\d+)\((\d+)\) !i', $b['title'], $partsB);
    foreach ([2, 1, 3] as $i) {
        if ($partsA[$i] != $partsB[$i]) {
            return strnatcasecmp($partsA[$i], $partsB[$i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => B2(14) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => A3(14) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => G3(14) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [title] => A13(13) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [title] => A13(15) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => A13(16) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => B13(16) consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [title] => D13(15) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

)
```

Though I may have misunderstood your requirements on re-reading your original post.  You said 'alphabetical order' and I assumed the letter at the start of the string.  You may have meant the text following the parens, of course.  So this may not best suit your needs but may help out.